# marker annotation clusters with clustering identifier set to nil

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

So I have two types of annotation views in my mapView: `MKAnnotationView` and 'MKMarkerAnnotationView'.

For both types, I don't want them to cluster and/or disappear when the user zooms out, so I did `annotationView.clusteringidentifier = nil` for both view types.

However, it seems only the `MKAnnotationView` doesn't cluster/disappear when zoomed out, and `MKMarkerAnnotationView` still disappears or clusters (I can't be sure because I'm zoomed out, but I think it might be disappearing rather than clustering when zoomed out).

Is there a property I can set in `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` to force mapView to display all annotations regardless of zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

set displayPriority = .required for the MKMarkerAnnotationView and all will be displayed.